# How to use Swift extensions in another module?

Tags: swift

I defined an extension in Swift in my app module and I want to use that extension in another module. Is it possible? I got compiler error "Type 'UserDefaults' has no member 'Keys'" when I used it in another module.

```
public extension UserDefaults {
    public enum Keys {
        public static let aaa = "aaa"
        public static let bbb = "bbb"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `import` that module?

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about it. Thanks.